# Search Strings Typed from View for Two Fields 'First Name' and 'Last Name' Combined

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Currently, I have a search box so that when you type anything in it, will show that keyword. But if I want to type two keywords, I'd like to return these combined keywords and find it from database.

On my Index method in a controller:

```
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            result = result.Where(b =>
                b.LastName.Contains(searchString) || b.FirstName.Contains(searchString)
                || b.Id.ToString().Contains(searchString)
                || b.Email.Contains(searchString)
                || b.City.Contains(searchString)
                || b.State.ToString().Contains(searchString)
                || b.FirstName.Contains(searchString)
                || b.FirstName.Contains(searchString) && b.LastName.Contains(searchString) // was trying to do something like this... I tried adding a FullName property and concactenated FirstName and LastName... didn't like it
                );
            ...
        }
```

View:

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Search first name, last name, city, state, ID", @type = "search" })
```

When you search with two fields it shows:

```
http://localhost:59818/Broker?SearchString=Some+Name
```

There was no result. Obviously I'm setting this up wrong? Or is there away to follow my current architecture so that I can simply pass combined keywords and displays it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to split those words into array.

```
var query = _context.Users.AsQueryable();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
   string[] collection = searchString.Split(' ', ',');
   foreach(var item in collection)
   {    
      query = query.Where(b =>
                b.LastName.Contains(item) 
                || b.FirstName.Contains(item)
                || b.Id.ToString().Contains(item)
                || b.Email.Contains(item)
                || b.City.Contains(item)
                || b.State.Contains(item));
   }
}

var result = query.ToList();
```

***Note:*** If you have too many `or` statements, it'll slow down the query.